# Recorrer y mostrar array en json

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy intentando recorrer un `json` para que muestre el curso, nombre alumno, área y notas. El json en cuestión es este:

```
{
   "5B":{
      "María":{
         "Educación Artística":[
            "10 8"
         ],
         "Educación Física":[
            "10 9"
         ],
         "Lengua Castellana y Literatura":[
            "8 7"
         ]
      },
      "Antonio":{
         "Educación Artística":[
            "9 7"
         ],
         "Educación Física":[
            "7 7"
         ],
         "Lengua Castellana y Literatura":[
            "6 8"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

El caso es que solo puedo mostrar el curso, nombre del alumno y notas.

El problema es que no soy capaz de mostrar el nombre del área. Si alguien de vosotr@s podéis lanzar algo de luz.

El código para recorrer el json es el siguiente:

```
for (var curso in data) {
    console.log("Curso: " + curso);

    for (var alumno in data[curso]) {
        console.log("nombre: " + alumno);

        for (var area in data[curso][alumno]) {
            console.log("Area: " + data[curso][alumno]); //sale [object][object]
            //console.log("Area: " + data[curso][alumno][area]);// sale la nota no el nombre del área
            for (var nota in data[curso][alumno][area]) {
                console.log("Nota: " + data[curso][alumno][area][nota]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

La salida que consigo reproducir es esta (El área me marca como objeto):

```
Curso: 5B
nombre: María
Area: [object Object]
Nota: 10 8
Area: [object Object]
Nota: 10 9
Area: [object Object]
Nota: 8 7
nombre: Antonio
Area: [object Object]
Nota: 9 7
Area: [object Object]
Nota: 7 7
Area: [object Object]
Nota: 6 8
```

Muchas gracias a tod@s.

Comment: Cambia esto: `console.log("Area: " + data[curso][alumno]);` por esto otro: `console.log("Area: " + area);`. Comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Con que lenguaje esta trabajando, java??

Comment: @isaac a jusgar por la sintaxis es JavaScript...

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya ha quedado solucionado. Tanto Juan José como  Mauricio han dado en el clavo. El lenguaje usado es javascript, Isaac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una errata que es muy fácil de solucionar:

Cuando haces:

```
console.log("Area: " + data[curso][alumno]);
```

deberías hacer:

```
console.log("Area: " + area);
```

Ya que al hacer el for estás declarando que área es `data[curso][alumno]` arrastrando los índices de los for anteriores.

Comment: Mil gracias, Juan José. Me resolviste el problema. Mira que estuve usando esa misma estructura de instrucción en los bucles anteriores, pero no sé porqué me empeñé en que tenía que hacerlo mediante los índices.